# MongoDB: using modulo to compute sharding key

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'am going to move my 500 millions rows table from postgresql to sharded collection in MongoDB.
I am in the middle of choosing proper sharding key.

Table Posts(id, users_id,title,content). Each post belongs to specified user. Users have from 100 to 1 million posts.

Is it possible to set sharding key as modulo from users_id (e.g. users_id % 128)? I query database by WHERE users_id.

Is it possible? Is it good idea? I am asking, because when i haven't found anything about using module in shadring key.

Comment: Based on your description, a user could have 1 million posts. Do you mean there could be 1 million documents share the same users_id? If so, the shard key on {users_id} has a low cardinality, meaning that there could be a lot of documents share the same shard key value and would not be able to split. You may consider shard the collection on a compound index like {users_id, _id}. You can refer to http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/ for more details about choosing a shard key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want your shard key to be `{users_id: 'hashed'}`, this way MongoDB will take care of the distribution for you.  Read more here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/shard-collection-with-a-hashed-shard-key/

Comment: Thx for that advic. J don't understand one thing. Why hashed shared key {users_id:'hashed'} would be better than normal shared key {users_id:1}?

Comment: it ensures you get a more even (random) distribution, if you don't need to do any range queries on `users_id`